# What word is used for young horsemen?

Tags: meaning, nouns, synonyms

What word do you use for young horsemen? Like teens or children who are skilled in riding, caring for, or managing horses.

Comment: If you're asking for a single word, Walid, you need to tick the 'single word request' tag and supply an example sentence with a blank space.

Comment: Whatever the solution, hopefully it will adopt the modern approach of avoiding gendered words like "horsemen".

Answer (score 0):

From Google: what does a stable hand do? **Stablehands** or **grooms** work in stables and look after horses, keeping them clean, comfortable, fed, exercised and groomed. They may take special care of foals.

However, I cannot vouch for them as being skilled riders.

Comment: ...or of being teens / children.

Comment: @Weather Vane. Have I missed the point of the question?

Comment: What the question brought to my mind was someone who really knows how to ride, such as those who do American barrel racing. In UK at least, few young people would have the opportunity to spend enough time in the saddle to gain that kind of skill, and I don't know of word specifically for a young rider, though in UK a skilled competitor might be called an *equestrian*. Perhaps there is an AmE colloquiallism, where horse culture is still quite big in rural areas, that describes such a person.

Comment: I often get pulled up for nor reading the question carefully, however, isn't the OP likening their expected answer to teens or children, as an example, Many youngsters, 'horse people', cut ther teeth in stables. For example Jockey: 'Most Jockeys begin their careers as Stable Hands and those with real potential and aptitude are selected to train as jockeys after graduating from a racing school' (https://www.animal-job.co.uk/career-with-horses.html).

Answer (score 0):

A person (usually young) who tends to horses at race tracks is a 'strapper'.

Comment: I worked at a racetrack during high school, and my peers and I (regardless of age) were known as grooms, not strappers.

Answer (score 0):

"Equestrian" is the word that I have heard young competitive riders use to describe themselves.  Where "competitive" indicates a certain achievement of skill.  But, I believe that "equestrian" covers all ages. "Young Equestrians" is the name that magazines appear to use to differentiate their market.